# GROUP BY with HAVING but unrecognized table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, and I am trying to split the answer column RES (that is divided by commas) into more rows (instead). But when I try to do that, the HAVING part is not working at all, and it's throwing: Unknow column.

This is the original query:

```
SELECT ad.ID_ANSWER as idRes
     , IFNULL(c.NOMBRE_FACTURA,a.INTERVIEWED_NAME) AS nomPdv
     , c.CODIGO
     , q.`NAME` AS nombreEncuesta
     , ad.ID_QUESTION AS idCue
     , que.QUESTION
     , GROUP_CONCAT(ad.ANSWER) AS RES
     , a.LATITUDE
     , a.LONGITUDE
     , cm.DIRECCION
     , c.NIT
     , cm.NOMREPRESENTANTE
     , cm.FECHA_NACIMIENTO
     , a.ID_QUESTIONARY
     , cm.TELEFONO, cm.FECHA_NACIMIENTO, cm.NITREPRESENTANTE,
CONCAT(cm.APELLIDO_PATERNO,' ',cm.APELLIDO_MATERNO,' ', cm.NOMBRES_CLIENTE) as RAZONSOCIAL, a.USUARIO_ID, a.FECHA_ID, R.NOMBRE AS RUTA, CASE WHEN D.NOMBRE IS NULL THEN DP.NOMBRE ELSE D.NOMBRE END AS DEPARTAMENTO, P.NOMBRE AS ENCUESTADOR
FROM VM_ANSWER AS a
JOIN VM_ANSWER_DETAIL ad 
    ON ad.ID_ANSWER = a.ID_ANSWER
JOIN VM_QUESTIONARY AS q 
    ON q.ID_QUESTIONARY = a.ID_QUESTIONARY
JOIN VM_QUESTION AS que 
    ON que.ID_QUESTION = ad.ID_QUESTION
JOIN VM_QUESTIONARY_RANGE AS qr 
    on qr.ID_QUESTIONARY = a.ID_QUESTIONARY
   AND qr.OPERACION_ID = 1
JOIN AD_USUARIO U 
    ON U.USERNAME = a.USUARIO_ID
JOIN GL_PERSONA P 
    ON P.ID_PERSONA = U.ID_PERSONA
LEFT 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM VP_VENDEDOR V GROUP BY V.ID_PERSONA) V ON V.ID_PERSONA = U.ID_PERSONA
LEFT JOIN VP_SUCURSAL S ON S.ID_SUCURSAL = V.ID_SUCURSAL
LEFT JOIN GL_DEPARTAMENTO D ON D.ID_DEPARTAMENTO = S.ID_DEPARTAMENTO
LEFT JOIN VP_CLIENTE AS c ON c.ID_CLIENTE = a.ID_CLIENT
LEFT JOIN VM_CLIENTE_MOVIL AS cm ON cm.ID_CLIENTE = c.ID_CLIENTE
LEFT JOIN GL_DEPARTAMENTO DP ON DP.ID_DEPARTAMENTO = cm.ID_CIUDAD
LEFT JOIN VM_RUTA_VENDEDOR RV ON RV.ID_VENDEDOR = V.ID_VENDEDOR AND RV.OPERACION_ID > 0
LEFT JOIN VM_RUTA R ON R.ID_RUTA = RV.ID_RUTA
WHERE a.OPERACION_ID = 1 AND qr.ID_BRANCH = 3 AND IF (61 = 0, TRUE, a.ID_QUESTIONARY = 61)
GROUP BY a.ID_QUESTIONARY,a.ID_ANSWER
ORDER BY a.ID_QUESTIONARY,a.ID_ANSWER
```

When I add the following code

```
LEFT JOIN GL_TIPO T ON T.ID_TIPO = que.ID_TYPE 
WHERE a.OPERACION_ID = 1 AND qr.ID_BRANCH = 3 AND IF (61 = 0, TRUE, a.ID_QUESTIONARY = 61)
GROUP BY a.ID_QUESTIONARY,a.ID_ANSWER, ad.ID_ANSWER_DETAIL HAVING T.ID_TIPO=1012
ORDER BY a.ID_QUESTIONARY,a.ID_ANSWER
```

throws me the error of not recognized table T.ID_TIPO, but if I take off the HAVING word, the left join works normally.

this is the normal result, that as you can see in the column RES, it's divided by a comma when there is more than an answer:

[image]

I know it's complicated to understand, 1012 is a multi-select answer type from table GL_TIPO, and it's used in the table Question to define the type of it.

If you can help me to understand what I am doing wrong with the HAVING reserved word it would be awesome, but if you have any suggestion is also welcome too.

Comment: `HAVING` can only refer to columns in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: See if you can simplify your problem, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @KenWhite you mean ORDER BY after HAVING?

Comment: Oops! I read it wrong. My mistake.

Comment: @Barmar is there a possibility to use GROUP BY if that id = 1012?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. `HAVING` is processed *after* grouping. That's why it can't refer to columns that aren't selected, because they don't appear in the groups.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just put `AND que.ID_TYPE = 1012` in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @Barmar because I need other types also, just need to split the answers with 1012 multi answer

Comment: How would `HAVING` split the answers? It filters the results to only that value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GROUP BY a.ID_QUESTIONARY,a.ID_ANSWER, que.ID_TIPO=1012
```

This will put the questions with `ID_TIPO=1012` into its own row, and all other `ID_TIPO` values will be grouped together. Both of these are nested within the `ID_QUESTIONARY, ID_ANSWER` groups.